# Place an image vertically and horizontally aligned HTML

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, haml

I want to place images inside a carrousel aligned both horizontal and vertical. This is my code:

```
#c-slide.carousel.slide.auto.panel-body{style: "height: 360px;"}
    .carousel-inner
        - if pictures.length>0
            .item.active{style: "text-align:center"}
                %a.vehicle-image{"data-toggle"=>"modal", "data-target"=>"#myModal"}
                    %img{"src"=>pictures.first.url, style: "max-height: 300px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"}
                - pictures.drop(1).each do |p|
                    .item{style: "text-align:center"}
                        %a.vehicle-image{"data-toggle"=>"modal", "data-et"=>"#myModal"}     
                            %img{"src"=>p.url, style: "max-height: 300px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"}
```

For those who doesn't know HAML, it's a simple bootstrap carousel, with images from a model.

Actually is only aligning horizontally, so the big question is..how can I do to also align it vertically?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
.item.active{style: "text-align:center"}
```

with

```
.item.active{style: "text-align:center; vertical-align:text-top;"}
```

If that isn't what you want see here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

If that still isn't what you want I would need more info about what you're trying to do. Depending on what you're doing vertical alignment doesn't work the same everywhere in HTML

Comment: I edited my post. The main problem is I'm setting the carousel height by 360px. The `vertical-align:text-top ` didn't work for me. Thoughts?

Comment: You probably going to have to do something hacky then. Like I said previously the web wasn't designed for this, originally everything was supposed to be crammed to the left and top, which is why html ignores white space. Check this out http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html I typically use method 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.carousel-inner>.item>img {
margin: 0 auto;
height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Had no luck. Thoughts?

Comment: How is your carousel placed on page? fixed or relative, try adding some more code here.

Comment: I think there's no other necessary code. The carousel is inside a div with class col-sm-4 but I don't think if that helps. Also, it has the default boostrap css.